# iOS Programing, making phone calls

Tags: ios, phone-call

Is it possible to make a call from my app without accessing the standart phone application?

The problem is that if I make a call, my app goes to the background, and I really do not need that. I need it to be always active even if I am calling.

Comment: The user can go back to your app after the call is made...

Comment: Why would your app have to be active when in a call?  The user probably isn't interested in interacting with your app at that point, what with the call holding their attention.

Comment: I have one condition, if something goes wrong the app is calling the landline phone of the user and the application keeps  calling him back

Answer (score 6):

No there is no way to do that, you can only make calls via de `tel` URL sheme.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tel://123456789, but this will display a confirmation before opening the phone app.

There are a few apps, however, that open the phone app and make a call directly without displaying a confirmation (like Dialvetica).

To answer your question, *no*, you can *not* make calls directly from your app, unless you create your own version of Skype (the whole network, not just the app), and you probably don't have the time, money and resources to do that.